# How to solve `IndexError: list index out of range` in python opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I have 94 different images, and I'm iterating it and appending it to other `list()`. Here's my code:

```
 while j < 94:
    b_list.append(feature_matrix_db[j])
    dist = spatial.distance.euclidean(a_list,b_list[j])
    result_list.append(dist)
    resultlist_key = OrderedDict(sorted(enumerate(result_list),key=lambda x: x[0])).keys()
    j = j + 1
```

`feature_matrix_db` contains the features of all the 94 images in the database. And my program will execute till this code, and it will stop working. I have declared `j = 0`, still I'm getting this `IndexError: list index out of range`

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: are you sure that you have exactly 94 images? You might try changing the number `94` to `len(feature_matrix_db)`.

Comment: Why would you sort the output of `enumerate` by the indices? You just get the index-value pairs back in the exact same order you already had. And then passing that to `OrderedDict` and getting the `keys`? That looks like an order-preserving deduplication routine, but you don't have any duplicates to remove. The whole mess is just equivalent to `range(len(result_list))` - and then you don't do anything with `resultlist_key` anyway. You just throw it away on the next iteration.

Comment: @anirudh Yes I have only 94 images in the data base.

Comment: Which line is the error occurring on? You should post the full error message, as well as a SSCCE (http://www.sscce.org/) so that others can test & debug your code.

Comment: @user2357112 `resultlist_key` contains the `key` along with the `value` . I'm using `OrderedDict` just to maintain the input sequence of the images, so that the sort will not change the `key` and the `value` will get sorted, and retrieval will be easy.

Comment: @varsha_holla: With the way you've constructed it? It's just a list of ints from `0` to `len(result_list)-1`. If you meant for it to be something else, you're building it wrong.

Comment: @varsha_holla Please post the traceback of the error that you get. Also,you could try the code in http://www.codeskulptor.org/viz/index.html where you could paste the code and click on the viz mode button to see a graphical representation of the code, line by line. It is a great debugger and helps me a lot.

Comment: @anirudh Thanks for the suggestion. I came to know the problem, its with pre-processing. Its not reading the images properly,and its not showing any error. This created a big issue. Sorry for killing your time :(